wave drag: Lift coefficient in Korn's Equation
I have been using the Korn equation:
$$
M_c = \frac{0.95}{cos(\lambda)}-\frac{t/c}{cos(\lambda)^2}-\frac{C_L}{10cos(\lambda)^3}-\sqrt[3]{\frac{0.1}{80}}
$$
to estimate the critical mach number of a swept wing, but I am now suddenly doubting the 3rd term.
The lift coefficient over a swept airfoil at transonic speeds is lower than incompressible theory would suggest, and there are various corrections used to allow you to use incompressible theory.
My question is, is that taken into account in the Korn equation above, such that I can just do the usual $C_L = \frac{2L}{SM^2p\gamma}$ or do I need to use a corrected lift coefficient?
N.B. the Korn equation was for airfoils wasn't it, and I am trying to use it for an entire wing...is this whole usage flawed?

Korn never wrote the Korn equation.
Korn made the observation that the critical Mach number of airfoils displayed a linear relationship with t/c and design lift coefficient.
Others introduced the airfoil technology factor (the 0.95 here) and corrections for application to 3D wings.  The cube root of 0.1/80 appears to be a correction between drag divergence and critical Mach numbers.
So, when you're using a complex 'Korn Equation' like this, you really have to follow your references back to who derived it.  There is a bunch of related work that likely leads to Mason or Takahashi or a few others.
In any case, make sure you have a good source for your 'Korn Equation' and then use it the way the author describes in their paper.

Thanks Rob, yeah that's kind of the issue, I can't find a source for this one...Guess I'll keep looking, I'll check out Mason and Takahashi!

If you're using an equation from a source that either doesn't cite where it comes from -- or very clearly explain everything about it -- it probably isn't a good source.  Check out this reference https://archive.aoe.vt.edu/mason/Mason_f/ConfigAeroTransonics.pdf Note also that the user of upper case Lambda $\Lambda$ is for sweep, where lower case lambda $\lambda$ is often used for taper ratio.
